# Hazelcast Near-Cache not working

Tags: hazelcast

I'm currently working on integrating Hazelcast to our system and was trying out near caching but I can across this issue.

I am doing hazelcast configuration through spring with our configuration being:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:management-center
            enabled="true"
            url="sanitized"
            update-interval="5" />
        <hz:network port="5701">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:members>#{systemProperties['hazelcast.members']}</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
            <hz:interfaces>
                <hz:interface>192.168.24.*</hz:interface>
            </hz:interfaces>
        </hz:network>
        <hz:map name="default" merge-policy="package.CustomMergePolicy">
<!--              near cache with default values -->
          <hz:near-cache
              cache-local-entries="false"
              eviction-policy="LRU"
              in-memory-format="BINARY"
              invalidate-on-change="true"
              max-idle-seconds="0"
              max-size="0"
              time-to-live-seconds="0"
          />
        </hz:map>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

First node started is throwing the following warning

```
Nov 04, 2014 4:46:23 PM com.hazelcast.map.operation.InvalidateNearCacheOperation
WARNING: [192.168.24.26]:5701 [dev] [3.3.1] Cache clear operation has been accepted while near cache is not enabled for CACHE_AFI.sessionsLastActivityPlus map. Possible configuration conflict among nodes.
```

Both nodes have the same exact configuration (configuration is packaged and copied to both nodes).

Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: Further testing has shown that Warning is always being displayed on the first node that is started (regardless which node is running the test). Additionally, using the management center we confirmed that both nodes have the same configuration, but it seems that the first node to be started is not activating near-caching a some of the maps.

Comment: Can you create a bug report on github? https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast

Comment: Ok, will do so as soon as I have a break